# Bootstrap.Tabs view does not show selected tab as active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-data

One of my templates is showing some bootstrap tabs:

```
{{view Bootstrap.Tabs
    contentBinding="controller.content"
    selectionBinding="controller.selection"}}
```

With the following model:

```
SettingsApp.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        var model = Ember.A([
            Ember.Object.create({title:t('profile.user'),      link:'#/profile/user'}),
            Ember.Object.create({title:t('profile.company'),   link:'#/profile/company'}),
            Ember.Object.create({title:t('profile.product'),   link:'#/profile/products/index'}),
        ]);
        return model;
    },
});
```

This is working fine: the tabs are displayed and the links are working. When a tab is clicked, the corresponsing route is activated, *but* the Bootstrap.Tabs view is not highlighting the selected option. All options are shown as inactive.

In my (complex) application I am doing the same thing as in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uCUboCo/5), but the jsbin is working as expected: the tab is shown as active when selected.

What could be going wrong in my application? Any debugging suggestion for this strange phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

To digg more into the inner workings of the [`Ember.LinkView`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkView.html) which is the view that get's instantiated for the `{{#linkTo}}` helper you could observe it's `active` property and check if it get's changed also in your (complex) application.

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
  activeChanged: function() {
    console.log('active');
  }.observes('active')
});
```

I've added this to your [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/UheS/3/edit) and there it is obviously working correctly.

Hope it helps